# How to identify a visitor session and serve only 1 popup per session

Tags: javascript, ajax

Thanks for your help in advance.

I am trying to track a user whilst they browse my website. I want to show them a popup window when they arrive, regardless of which page they land on. But when they go to another page I dont want to keep annoying them with the same popup.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
// when popup is run
sessionStorage.popped = 'yes';

// just test
if(!sessionStorage.popped){
  // popup now
}
// when running your popup
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually set a localstorage on the HTML with javascript.

```
localStorage.setItem("visited", "yes");
```

and check it by using

```
localStorage.getItem("visited");
```

That way you can check if they have already visited or not.

Comment: You beat me to it. Yes, local storage makes this easy :)

Comment: Thank you. How long will this save this information? What if they close the window and return?

Comment: @RobbieP14383 it will last until the browser cache/cookie (depends on the browser) is cleared.

Comment: For a session, use `sessionStorage` instead.

Comment: @GabrielB.R thanks very much. is there a way to clear the cookie/cache using code on exit?

Comment: @RobbieP14383 You can remove it `localStorage.removeItem("visisted");`

Comment: @PHPglue sessionStorage only persist on the exact same window. If you open another window or close the current one, the visitor will get the popup again.